# SurfaceView overlaps another SurfaceView on Android 8.0

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-8.0-oreo, android-8.1-oreo

I'm facing some strange issue with my app on Android 8.0. I have my own scrollable widget, code is [available on github](https://github.com/amostyaev/SwipeLayout). It has two childs, which can be scrolled one by one indefinitely.

On the screen, the chess board is a SurfaceView and a scrollable moving child with chess pieces on it is also a SurfaceView. Another child of a scrollable view is simple LinearLayout.

The problem is when child SurfaceView is placed below the chess board, it is showed above it, while another child scrolls normally. Look at the gif below.

[image]

The problem appeared on Android 8. On all previous versions it worked fine.

Comment: Have you tried providing your chess board `SurfaceView` z-elevation?

Comment: Thanks for the tip! `setZOrderMediaOverlay(true)` on chess board solved the problem. You may post your answer for a bounty. I'll edit the answer with additional details to help someone else in the future.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this to make **`SurfaceView`** to top of the screen:

```
surfaceView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
```

The main tip is not to use `setZOrderOnTop(true)`, as it displays `SurfaceView` above any UI element. `setZOrderMediaOverlay` displays the SurfaceView below the UI, but above another SurfaceView.

> More from [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html#setZOrderMediaOverlay(boolean))