# issue when Surfaceview Above Another Surfaceview swap in sony bravia tv

Tags: android, surfaceview

[image]

In my sample i need to swap big player and small player when clicking swap button but small player above big player is not visible,
i am setting elevation for container for the each fragment when doing swap but this does not seems like working with surfaceview but with textureview it is working,

i have tried fix which mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52329810/surfaceview-overlaps-another-surfaceview-on-android-8-0)

but that fix does not work for Sony Bravia TV.

Answer (score 0):

A SurfaceView is "just an hole" where Android renders the Surface, so it depends of Order or Creation. If you *Attach_to_window* the BIG SurfaceView before the SMALL one, then the second will stay over the first and there isn't any method to change this order for this Special kind of View (Android references reports that SurfaceView cannot be managed as a normal View which supports all transformations).

The only secure solution is to *Detach* both SurfaceViews and then re-attach them in the right order (or just swap internal Render Threads Canvas/Surface target if you're using Render Threads).